# How to install i386 gcc cross compiler on linux

Tags: linux, i386

#### Hi, how can i download i386 elf cross compiler on linux

**i need:**

- *i386-elf-gcc*
- *i386-elf-ld*

what commands i need to write in to cmd to get this packages?
Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

I think you could create your own binary cross compiler basing on sources from:
https://crosstool-ng.github.io/

The crosstool-ng are sources of the cross toolchain which you can configure on your own to achieve gcc and ld. The configuration process is similar to the configuration of linux kernel. It just uses "menuconfig" method for configuring all the things. Then you run compilation of this project and if everything go fine you will get cross toolchain.